# in angular js how to call a function if ng-if is true?

Tags: angularjs

i am totally new with angular js and trying to call a function when ng-if is true
my code =>

```
ng-repeat="image in post.postImages" ng-if="$index <= 3" ng-init="image.showDeleteIcon= false && hellow()"
```

and my js =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $scope.hellow = function ()
       {
           alert('hi');
       };
</script>
```

also try=>

```
<span ng-if="$index === 3" ng-init="hellow()"></span>
```

problem is it is not alerting anything ?can anybody tell me what i have done wrong?

Comment: Size of post.postImages please?

Comment: 8..................

Comment: You have to define Angular Controller to handle `$scope.hellow` function.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
ng-repeat="image in post.postImages" ng-if="$index <= 3" ng-init="image.showDeleteIcon= false; hellow()";
```

Comment: its calling method once ng-init value is assigned

Comment: then ng-if is not true,

Answer (score 0):

Define `angular`(`module and ng-app`) first and then `controller` to bind the function `hellow`., then change it like :

```
  <div ng-repeat="image in post.postImages" ng-if="$index <= 3" ng-init="image.showDeleteIcon=false; hellow();">
```

Working 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aeewckd/)

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u99nj8g/) with script tag.

Comment: is not the same posted above?

Comment: in angular js if i only write   $scope.hellow = function() {
    alert('hi');

  }; inside a script tag. will it not going to work????

Comment: @Sajeetharan : in Qstn. it is written `image.showDeleteIcon= false && hellow()`, and in your answer (before edit) `hellow()` was outside the `ng-init`.

Comment: @nayanchowdhury: yes it will work, but angular need to be defined and  bootstrap, See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u99nj8g/)